# Perl Error "Can't call method "get_tag" on an undefined value at Parser.pl line 6"

Tags: perl, html-parsing, www-mechanize, html-parser

I wrote a simple perl script but i am getting this runtime error:

Can't call method "get_tag" on an undefined value at Parser.pl line 6

Below is my code:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use HTML::TokeParser
my $p=HTML::TokeParser->new('bad.html');
while (my $token=$p->get_tag('a')){
my $url=$token->[1]{href};
print "$url\n";
}
```

I have placed a file bad.html under the same directory of this perl program.
Below is the code for bad.html

```
<html><body>
<a href="https://www.Google.com">Google</a>
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
</body></html>
```

Please help me on the error in running my perl code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem of not using:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

They **save** you **hours**! You missed a `;` in the line `use HTML::TokeParser`.

You could write the script in a better way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TokeParser;

my $p = HTML::TokeParser->new('bad.html');
while ( my $token = $p->get_tag('a') ) {
    my $url = $token->[1]{href};
    print "$url\n";
}
```

Comment: Thats awesome.. Just a very small mistake from my side only.. Thanks a lot guys.